# Drawing a data relationship diagram using networkx and matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a data relationship diagram. I've modeled my input data in triples (subject, predicate, object) e.g. (app, 'consumes', entity), (app, 'masters', entity), etc
Each triple is an edge and 2 nodes. I want to color different sets of nodes in different colors as well. 
I'm struggling with setting the color attribute as well as saving the graph to a png file in a size that is readable

Here's the code :

```
G = nx.DiGraph ()
```

read input data from file and process is lists of nodes and edges
......
add nodes - set diff color for each set of nodes ??

```
G.add_nodes_from (list(entities), node_color='yellow')
G.add_nodes_from (list(sornodes))
G.add_nodes_from (list (consumernodes))
```

add edges - set diff color for each set of edges (how do I do this?)

```
G.add_edges_from (masters)
G.add_edges_from (consumers)
G.add_edges_from (ads)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1700)
nx.draw_networkx_edges (G, pos, arrow=True)
nx.draw_networkx_labels (G, pos)
nx.draw_spring (G)

plt.figure(figsize=(7.195, 3.841))
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.savefig ('out.png', dpi=1000)
plt.show ()
```

There is no image in the file. plt.show pops up the graph in a new window and another empty window is opened as well. I'm running this from a bash shell. Closing both the image windows terminates the program.

- I need to be able to show sets of nodes in different colors.
- I need to be able to show sets of edges in different colors
- I want to be able to size the graph to a large image - does not need to fit within a monitor size

Thoughts anyone ?

Comment: OK. I found the solution. The answer is to pass a list of colors to draw_networkx_labels. nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=nodecolor, node_size=1700)

Answer (score 0):

draw_networkx_nodes (...) does not seem like to multiple calls with different sets of nodes and different colors for each set. It uses the last color specified for all the nodes in the graph.
The solution is to call draw_networkx_nodes once and pass a list with colors for each node and list len same as number of nodes.

```
# s, c and a are 3 lists of nodes

for x in s:
    nodes.append(x)
    nodecolor.append('r')
for x in c:
    nodes.append(x)
    nodecolor.append('g')
for x in a:
    nodes.append(x)
    nodecolor.append('y')

G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=nodecolor, node_size=1700)
```

I'm sure I could optimize the code for creating the lists.